# How to bind data collection with Custom Template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I wanted to avoid scrolling `ListView`'s `Header`, so I've created custom controll for List, which consists of grid with two rows (first of them is header and in second I could place the `ListView`, but I've successfully binded header with controll, but I can't do the same with data.

My `ListViewCustomControl` class:

```
   public sealed class ListViewCustomControl : Control
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Header", typeof(string), typeof(ListViewCustomControl),
            new PropertyMetadata("custom_template_row1"));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ElementsSource", typeof(IObservable<Type>), typeof(ListViewCustomControl),
            null);


        public ListViewCustomControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ListViewCustomControl);
        }

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        public IObservable<Type> ElementsSource
        {
            get { return (IObservable<Type>)GetValue(ElementsSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ElementsSourceProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

Style for my control:

```
<Style TargetType="local:ListViewCustomControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ListViewCustomControl">
                <Grid Background="BlueViolet">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"></TextBlock>
                    <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                              ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ElementsSource}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TypeVar}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Sample of using in xaml file:

```
        <local:ListViewCustomControl
            Header="yolo" ElementsSource="{Binding data}">
        </local:ListViewCustomControl>
```

sent data and `Type` definition

```
private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
{
    var data = new List<Type>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 123; i++) data.Add(new Type(i));
    defaultViewModel["data"] = data;
}
public class Type
{
    public int TypeVar { get; set; }

    public Type(int i)
    {
        TypeVar = i;
    }
}
```

As I've mentioned on the beginning. Header property works well, but I can't make data binding working well too...

**update**

I've noticed in debugger that `SetValue` function from `XamlTypeInfo.g.cs` has been invoked once, only to set `Header` value.

**update**

I've changed `IObservable` to `IList` and what's more important default value of `ElementsSourceProperty` and it works for default value, but I still can't change this value...

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ElementsSource", typeof(IList<Type>), typeof(ListViewCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            new List<Type>(3)
            {
                new Type(4), new Type(5), new Type(6)
            }));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change type of `ElementsSource`:

```
IObservable<>
```

to:

```
IList<>
```

like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ElementsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ElementsSource", typeof(IList<Type>), typeof(ListViewCustomControl),
        null);

public IList<Type> ElementsSource
{
    get { return (IList<Type>)GetValue(ElementsSourceProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ElementsSourceProperty, value); }
}
```

For test, try set for `ListView` name and write this line in code-behind:

```
MyListView.ElementsSource = data;
```

**`Version with Binding`**

In this case, you must specify the `DataContext`, which would you want us to list:

`XAML`

```
<local:ListViewCustomControl Header="yolo"
                             ElementsSource="{Binding TestList}" />
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var testData = new TestData();
        testData.TestList = new List<Type>();

        for (var i = 0; i < 123; i++)
            testData.TestList.Add(new Type(i));

        this.DataContext = testData;
    }
}

public class TestData 
{
    public List<Type> TestList
    {
        get; 
        set; 
    }
}
```

**`Some notes`**

- You can choose the type of `IEnumerable`, because it is the base class for all collections.
- When you create a dependency property you can skip `PropertyMetadata`, in this case, the system will automatically assign a default value for this type.

Comment: still don't work. I updated my post according to observation that ElementsSource isn't even set.

Comment: @Jakub Kuszneruk: Type also can on the `IEnumerable` type, the question is what it means: `defaultViewModel ["data"] = data;`. You need to deal with `Binding`. Try set for ListView name and write this line: `MyListView.ElementsSource = data;`.

Comment: it works in Code-behind, but how can I bind `data` list in xaml file?

Comment: It works when I explicitly set ElementSource to list, but won't work for your binding proposition.

Comment: @Jakub Kuszneruk: [`Here`](http://1drv.ms/1ee2RtP) link to my project where Binding works fine.

Comment: Thank you, I adapted your project to Windows8.1 App, but still the same situation.

Comment: @Jakub Kuszneruk: What exactly does not work? Collection appears in `ListView`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49327/discussion-between-jakub-kuszneruk-and-anatoliy-nikolaev)